# Using grep to get the line number of first occurrence of a string in a file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am using bash script for testing purpose.During my testing I have to find the line number of first occurrence of a string in a file. I have tried "awk" and "grep" both, but non of them return the value.

Awk example

```
#/!bin/bash
....
VAR=searchstring
...
cpLines=$(awk '/$VAR/{print NR}' $MYDIR/Configuration.xml
```

this does not expand $VAR. If I use the value of VAR it works, but I want to use VAR

Grep example

```
#/!bin/bash
...
VAR=searchstring    
...
cpLines=grep -n -m 1 $VAR $MYDIR/Configuration.xml |cut -f1 -d:
```

this gives error line 20: -n: command not found

Answer (score 21):

```
grep -n -m 1 SEARCH_TERM FILE_PATH |sed  's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

**grep switches**

-n = include line number

-m 1 = match one

**sed options (stream editor):**

`'s/X/Y/'` - replace X with Y

`\([0-9]*\)` - regular expression to match digits zero or multiple times occurred, escaped parentheses, the string matched with regex in parentheses will be the \1 argument in the Y (replacement string)

`\([0-9]*\).*` - `.*` will match any character occurring zero or multiple times.

Answer (score 9):

You need $() for variable substitution in grep

```
cpLines=$(grep -n -m 1 $VAR $MYDIR/Configuration.xml |cut -f1 -d: )
```

Answer (score 6):

Try something like:

```
awk -v search="$var" '$0~search{print NR; exit}' inputFile
```

In `awk`, `/ /` will interpret `awk` variable literally. You need to use `match` (`~`) operator. What we are doing here is looking for the variable against your input line. If it matches, we print the line number stored in `NR` and exit.

`-v` allows you to create an `awk` variable (`search`) in above example. You then assign it your `bash` variable (`$var`).

Comment: I like this one best because it uses only a single process.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -n -m 1 SEARCH_TERM FILE_PATH | grep -Po '^[0-9]+'
```

explanation:

```
 -Po = -P -o
```

`-P` use perl regex

`-o` only print matched string (not the whole line)

Answer (score 0):

Try pipping;

`grep -P 'SEARCH TERM' fileName.txt | wc -l`